# How to check that FTP server configured correctly?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ftp, vsftpd

How to check that FTP server configured correctly and ready to work? I mean, it should have preconfigured username and password and allow to receive files. VSFTPD was installed a long time ago, and I never used it. I don't remember what settings I changed at all. Vsftpd version 3.0.3.

Comment: "Configured Correctly" is a very *very* subjective opinion, of which only you can really determine if the configurations meet your needs.  (The average sysadmin will say "Don't use FTP at all" in response to "Is FTP configured right", since FTP is no longer a safe or secure protocol to use for anything).  Given the wide range of subjectivity you will get with regards to "Configured Correctly", you need to be more specific with what you're considering 'configured correctly' in order to properly get a specific-enough scope to your question.  (Otherwise, "Too Broad" could be the close reason)

Comment: I mean FTP server have preconfigured username and password and allow to receive files.

Answer (score 1):

Check what ports you have open with `netstat -tln`. use systemctl to restart the service and then use systemctl to check the status to see if it started correctly. Last try using it like you would expect a normal user to and see if that works.

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question of "configured correctly"

Comment: I checked this,  vsftpd FTP server is active (running). How to set username and password for secure communication?

Comment: They are already set. They are the credentials you already use to login to that box. 

The command will look something like this: `sftp <TargetMachine'sUser>@<TargetMachine'sIP>`

You can create a new user but that's a different question and I believe is already well covered on this site.

Comment: No, I have not set user credentials.

Comment: You need to have access to the other machine first. Whether that access is just a username and password provided to you or you need to setup the machine and then use that username and password.

Comment: If this solved your issue please mark the answer. :)